# How to optimize cudaHostAlloc and cudaLaunchKernel times in pytorch training

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, profiler

I am trying to profile my model with pytorch profiler. I used the below code to profile

```
with profile(activities=[ProfilerActivity.CPU, ProfilerActivity.CUDA], record_shapes=True) as prof:
    with record_function("model_inference"):
        output_batch = self.model(input_batch)
print(prof.key_averages().table(sort_by="cpu_time_total", row_limit=10))
```

The profiler output is as follows

```
-------------------------------------------------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  
                                                   Name    Self CPU %      Self CPU   CPU total %     CPU total  CPU time avg     Self CUDA   Self CUDA %    CUDA total  CUDA time avg    # of Calls  
-------------------------------------------------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  
                                        model_inference         3.17%      83.011ms        63.97%        1.675s        1.675s       0.000us         0.00%     373.844ms     373.844ms             1  
                                            aten::copy_         0.24%       6.333ms        39.93%        1.046s       1.504ms      28.758ms         7.69%      29.035ms      41.777us           695  
                                          cudaHostAlloc        36.02%     943.053ms        36.02%     943.053ms      30.421ms       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us            31  
                                       cudaLaunchKernel        35.93%     940.773ms        35.93%     940.773ms      86.619us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us         10861  
                                           aten::repeat         0.04%     979.000us        33.77%     884.170ms      30.489ms       0.000us         0.00%     204.000us       7.034us            29  
                                           aten::conv2d         0.06%       1.481ms         8.71%     228.183ms     695.680us       0.000us         0.00%     145.688ms     444.171us           328  
                                      aten::convolution         0.05%       1.391ms         8.66%     226.702ms     691.165us       0.000us         0.00%     145.688ms     444.171us           328  
                                     aten::_convolution         0.10%       2.742ms         8.61%     225.311ms     686.924us       0.000us         0.00%     145.688ms     444.171us           328  
                                aten::cudnn_convolution         0.53%      13.803ms         8.33%     218.051ms     664.790us     137.822ms        36.87%     137.822ms     420.189us           328  
                                               cudaFree         7.46%     195.373ms         7.46%     195.373ms      48.843ms       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             4  
-------------------------------------------------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  
Self CPU time total: 2.618s
Self CUDA time total: 373.844ms
```

I notice that a large part of the time (self CPU) is taken by `cudaHostAlloc` and `cudaLaunchKernel`. What are these `cudaHostAlloc` and `cudaLaunchKernel`? Is it possible to reduce this time? If yes how? Are there any standard operations that I'm missing which is leading to this high time consumption?

PS: I'm new to profiling as such. Kindly let me know if any other information is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert but I think cudaLaunchKernel is called at every operation done with cuda. So I think you cannot optimize it.

If you plot a detailed tracing https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/profiler_recipe.html#using-tracing-functionality, you see that it is called everytime you do a cuda operation like here for a linear layer.

[image: profiler tracing]

One note on you profiler output: `aten::copy_` `cudaHostAlloc` `cudaLaunchKernel` and `aten::repeat` all take roughly 40% of the CPU total time. I think it may be related to `ProfilerActivity.CUDA` that records CUDA operation but it also add **a lot** of CPU time on your first CUDA operation that is profiled. In my case a simple `torch.ones(1000, device="cuda")` took a full second of CPU time because it was the first cuda operation.

It may be the problem in your case, try to remove `ProfilerActivity.CUDA` and maybe `aten::copy_` `cudaHostAlloc` `cudaLaunchKernel` and `aten::repeat` will have a much smaller CPU time and will disappear from the table.