# What is cudaLaunchKernel in pytorch profiler output

Tags: python, pytorch, profiling

I'm trying to profile my pytorch network to see what is the bottleneck. I noticed that there is an operation called `cudaLaunchKernel` which is taking up most of the time. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69209389/3337089) says that it is called for every operation done with cuda. If suppose I implement this network in C++ or any other language, would it be possible to reduce this time?

Basically, I'm asking if this overhead is because I've implemented my network in python or will this overhead be always there and impossible to optimize in any language?

Full profiler output:

```
-------------------------------------------------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  
                                                   Name    Self CPU %      Self CPU   CPU total %     CPU total  CPU time avg     Self CUDA   Self CUDA %    CUDA total  CUDA time avg    # of Calls  
-------------------------------------------------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  
                                       cudaLaunchKernel        99.80%     933.739ms        99.80%     933.739ms      20.750ms       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us            45  
                                        model_inference         0.05%     453.000us       100.00%     935.567ms     935.567ms       0.000us         0.00%     195.000us     195.000us             1  
                                aten::cudnn_convolution         0.04%     388.000us        99.84%     934.047ms     103.783ms     195.000us       100.00%     195.000us      21.667us             9  
                                     aten::_convolution         0.01%     138.000us        99.88%     934.419ms     103.824ms       0.000us         0.00%     195.000us      21.667us             9  
                                           aten::conv2d         0.01%     122.000us        99.89%     934.592ms     103.844ms       0.000us         0.00%     195.000us      21.667us             9  
                                             aten::add_         0.01%     112.000us         0.02%     155.000us      17.222us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             9  
                               aten::upsample_nearest2d         0.01%      82.000us         0.01%     105.000us      26.250us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             4  
                                            aten::empty         0.01%      79.000us         0.01%      79.000us       3.292us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us            24  
                                        aten::threshold         0.01%      74.000us         0.02%     149.000us      18.625us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             8  
                                             aten::_cat         0.01%      71.000us         0.01%     119.000us      29.750us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             4  
                                             aten::relu         0.01%      57.000us         0.02%     206.000us      25.750us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             8  
                                      aten::convolution         0.01%      51.000us        99.88%     934.470ms     103.830ms       0.000us         0.00%     195.000us      21.667us             9  
                                             aten::view         0.01%      50.000us         0.01%      50.000us       5.556us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             9  
                                              aten::cat         0.00%      32.000us         0.02%     151.000us      37.750us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             4  
                                          aten::reshape         0.00%      29.000us         0.01%      79.000us       8.778us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             9  
                                          aten::resize_         0.00%      25.000us         0.00%      25.000us       0.962us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us            26  
                                             aten::rsub         0.00%      21.000us         0.00%      33.000us      33.000us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             1  
                                              aten::mul         0.00%      17.000us         0.00%      27.000us      27.000us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             1  
                                            aten::zeros         0.00%      13.000us         0.00%      16.000us      16.000us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             1  
                                        cudaEventRecord         0.00%      12.000us         0.00%      12.000us       1.333us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             9  
                                        cudaBindTexture         0.00%      11.000us         0.00%      11.000us       2.750us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             4  
                                    aten::empty_strided         0.00%       6.000us         0.00%       6.000us       6.000us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             1  
                                            aten::zero_         0.00%       1.000us         0.00%       1.000us       1.000us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             1  
cudnn::maxwell::gemm::computeOffsetsKernel(cudnn::ma...         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us     195.000us       100.00%     195.000us     195.000us             1  
                                      cudaUnbindTexture         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             4  
-------------------------------------------------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  
Self CPU time total: 935.583ms
Self CUDA time total: 195.000us
```

PS: Some configs
Python version: 3.8.8
PyTorch version: 1.8.1
cudatoolkit version: 10.2.89
cuda version (as given by nvidia-smi): 11.4

CPU specs: intel core i7 10700 @ 2.90GHz 16 cores
GPU specs: NVIDIA GM204GL [Quadro M4000]
RAM: 64GB
GPU RAM: 8GB
OS: 64-bit Ubuntu 20.04.3

PPS: I'm not looking for ways to speed up my code. I want to know **if it is possible** to speed it up by coding it in a different language like cpp or directly in cuda. (Like suppose if all my data is already on GPU, and I've written my code in cuda language itself, would it run in `195us`?)

Comment: Can you share your CUDA and PyTorch versions?

Comment: Added to the question. Thanks for the suggestions. Please let me know if anything more is required.

Comment: would be curious your cpu/gpu specs too. Could be a hardware related bottleneck where there's little you could do to optimize things on the software side

Comment: I've added cpu and gpu specs. Lemme know if anything more is needed (and how to get that). When you say hardware related bottleneck, do you mean time taken to move data from CPU-RAM to GPU-RAM or running convolutions and GPU operations itself?

Answer (score 2):

According to CUDA [docs](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/10.2/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__HIGHLEVEL.html#group__CUDART__HIGHLEVEL_1g7656391f2e52f569214adbfc19689eb3), `cudaLaunchKernel` is called to launch a **device function**, which, in short, is code that is run on a GPU device.

The profiler, therefore, states that a lot of computation is run on the GPU (as you probably expected) and this requires the data structures to be transferred on the device. This may be the source of the bottleneck.

I don't usually develop in CUDA, but perhaps you can speed up the process by coding larger kernels with more operation in CUDA and less CPU/GPU transferrals.

Have a look at [this tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_extension.html?highlight=pybind11_module) for more details.

Comment: "The profiler, therefore, states that a lot of computation is run on the GPU", how did you arrive at this conclusion? The profiler states that CPU operations take `935ms` and GPU operations take `195us`. So, most of the time is taken by CPU and not GPU, right?

Comment: My hypothesis is that the CPU is in charge of transferring the data from/to the GPU (therefore the high CPU time of `cudaLaunchKernel`), so coding a single CUDA kernel instead of calling many of them might result in a speedup.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Is there any way I can validate or find a reference for your hypothesis?

Comment: What about profiling a simple C++ program with a for cycle that calls many times `cudaLaunchKernel`, and comparing the performance with a program that calls a single `cudaLaunchKernel` with a for cycle inside it? Reading the CUDA docs or following some tutorials on the CUDA architecture may give you more insights too.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out. Can you check this question once? https://stackoverflow.com/q/71328622/3337089  unless I confirm that conv/CudaLaunchKernel methods take same amount of time, I can't do the c++ experiment, right?

Comment: Well, I was thinking you can start testing on a very simple model (e.g. a `Linear` layer). until you replicate the same phenomenon. It probably takes less than coding your entire model :)